# Dynamically changing innerText's start without eval()

Tags: javascript, html

I have some code (several batches) that look like this:

```
1    <div id="backgrounds" class="centery">Backgrounds
2        <div id="bk1" class="attr">Background 1
3            <div class="container">
4                <!-- Lots more HTML here /-->
5            </div>
6        </div>
7    </div>
```

I have a JS function I wrote (`changefirstCharacters`) that will return the script to change line 2 to read:

```
2        <div id="bk1" class="attr">Some text I specify
```

But because I want this to only execute when an event listener fires, it only outputs the code, rather than evaluating it. As a result, my event listener contains a line like this:

```
eval(changeFirstCharacters('bk1', "'" + document.getElementById('background1').value + "'"));
```

Where `background1` is a select box.

How can I re-write `changeFirstCharacters` to not need eval, but still work only when called?

## changeFirstCharacters() code

```
function changeFirstCharacters(id, newText) {
    return 'document.getElementById(\"' + id + '\").innerHTML = ' + newText + ' \+ document.getElementById(\"' + id + '\").innerHTML.substr(' + document.getElementById(id).innerText.length + ', document.getElementById(\"' + id + '\").innerHTML.length \-' + document.getElementById(id).innerText.length + ')';
}
```

Comment: I can't see what is the problem here? and also I don't see any use of eval here.

Comment: between "a line like this:" and "where `background1` is a select box". That line of code starts with `eval(`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see what's so dynamic about that statement. The only reason we need `eval` is when code is dynamically generated, but neither `newText` nor `id` changes the produced code. Therefore, the following ought to work:

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = newText + 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.substr(document.getElementById(id).innerText.length, 
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML.length - document.getElementById(id).innerText.length);
```

Called by (without adding quotes around the second argument):

```
changeFirstCharacters('bk1', document.getElementById('background1').value)
```

---

Also that first code calls `getElementById(id)` five times, which is not only a performance hit, it's rather ugly. You might want to rewrite it as:

```
var el = document.getElementById(id);

el.innerHTML = newText + el.innerHTML.substr(el.innerText.length, 
    el.innerHTML.length - el.innerText.length);
```